# What causes the origin of Batman?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, superman-red-son

In Superman: Red Son, we see Batman who is apparently now a Russian individual. Red Son is in DC's Elseworlds story arch AFAIK. So the origin of Bruce Wayne as Batman is not the Batman in Red Son. We don't get to see him without the mask in the movie, nor see any general Batman related status like Alfred/Butler, Wayne Manor/Mansion nor Bat-cave/a lair.

Whoever the Batman in Red Son is, his origin would not be the American Bruce Wayne story line.

What is the origin of Batman in Superman: Red Son? what causes the beginning of that Batman?

Answer (score 5):

From [villains.fandom.com](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_(Red_Son)):

> In an alternate reality, Batman became a ruthless anarchist after his parents are gunned down by Stalin's police force, vowing revenge on Pyotr Roslov and 20 years later became the most wanted man in the Soviet Union.

[From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman%3A_Red_Son#Plot) we learn that Pyotr Roslov was the head of the [NKVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NKVD). He shoots a dissident couple (batman's parents) in front of their son (who would later become Batman) for anti-Superman propaganda.

This version of Batman is an adaptation of the character that appears in the DC comic book [Superman: Red Son Vol 1 1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_Red_Son_Vol_1_1).